# Replace 0 with 1000 in Port 0 And increment by +1 in following lines

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to increment port numbers starting from 1000. I know how to make all port 0 when they are assigned numbers with this command

```
sed 's/port [0-9]\{1,5\}/port 0/g'
```

but do not know how to do the opposite. I have to change it in 2k lines in multiple script files.

- This is what I have

  ```
  local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 0 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869 
  local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 0 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869
  local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 0 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869
  local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 0 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869
  ```
- The desired output would look like:

  ```
  local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 1000 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869
  local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 1001 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869
  local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 1002 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869
  local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 1003 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869
  ```

Comment: Are the fields space- or tab-separated? Can there be empty lines, comment lines or other lines to be ignored?

Comment: Please don't post the same question on multiple sites - https://stackoverflow.com/q/66069216/1745001.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k=1000
m=$(echo "$k\\";printf '%s' {0..9})

sed -En "
  1{x;s/.*/$m/;x;}

  /local-ip/!{p;d;}
  G
  s/(port )0( .*)\n(.*)\n.*/\1\3\2/
  p;g;trst;:rst

  # port+1
  s/([0-8])(\n.*\1(.))/\3\2/;h;t
  s/(9+)\n/_&/
  :a;s/(_9*)9(0*\n)/\10\2/;ta
  s/^_/0&/
  s/(.)_(0+\n.*\1(.))/\3\2/
  h
"  file
```

**Output:**

```
local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 1000 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869 
local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 1001 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869
local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 1002 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869
local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 1003 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869
```

for increment by 1, we have to take care of two things. Whether the lsd is a non-9 or a run of consecutive 9s. In case of former we just replace the lsd by its next higher digit. And in case of latter we change all the lsd 9s to 0s and replace the neighbor with the next higher digit. Then store back in hold for next iteration

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do it in `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{p=1000} $1=="local-ip"{$4=p++} 1' input.cfg > output.cfg
```

This will parse all lines that start with `local-ip` (as a small safe-guard against empty or comment lines) and replace the 4th field (the current port number) with a consecutively increased number, starting at 1000.

**Update**

Since you stated in a comment that you want to do this for multiple files, you can use the following shell loop:

```bash
for f in input{1..16}.cfg; do n=${f/input/output}; awk 'BEGIN{p=1000} $1=="local-ip"{$4=p++} 1' "$f" > "$n"; done
```

This will loop over all files that match `input{1..16}.cfg`, replace the `input` with `output` to produce the output filename `n`, and applies the `awk` program stated above to each input/output pair. Note that the port numbers will be renumbered local to the file, i.e. each file restarts at port 1000.

Comment: this works for a single file, but can it work for multiple. I tried this

`awk 'BEGIN{p=1000} $1=="local-ip"{$4=p++} 1'  input{1..16}.cfg > output{1..16}-new.cfg`

Result

`-bash: output{1..16}-new.cfg: ambiguous redirect`

Comment: [I see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66069216/1745001) that you didn't accept this answer, accepted one that doesn't work for a single file instead, then posted a new question on SO using AdminBee's code as your starting point without even acknowledging it.

Comment: @EdMorton I am new to this forum. I did not know how to put a reference to the AdminBee code. But I should have known better, won't happen again.

Comment: You asked a question, you got an answer (this one), so accept it and if you have a followup question then post a new question (I can't imagine why you would go to a different form than the one you got this answer on for that, but whatever) and just say "I got this answer at...",  copy/paste the "share" link to it, and state what you additionally need to do.

Comment: @MuhammadIlyas I added instructions on how to do this in a bash loop for multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly simple with awk. For example:

```
awk 'BEGIN { portno=1000 }
           { print $1, $2, $3, portno++, $5, $6, $7, $8 }' inputfile
```

This assumes that the lines are all formatted like in your example.

Comment: The actual format look like this `local-ip 155.165.170.10 port 0 remote-ip 155.16.241.11 port 3869 origin-host home origin-realm city`

The result-  It deleted anything after **port 3869** It incremented the number for the ports but also continued the incrementation for all the lines in the script which does not have a **port**

Comment: In this case, you need to amend the question and correctly describe the input file(s). AdminBee's answer seems to fit your need better.

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two options.

**Option 1**: Run awk for each input file

```
# Loop over the input file numbers and run awk for each
for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do awk '$1=="local-ip"{$4=1000+p++;}1' input$i.txt > output$i.txt; done
```

**Option 2**: Create output files with awk directly

```
awk 'FNR==1{p=1000; sub("input", "output", FILENAME)} $1=="local-ip"{$4=p++} {print >> FILENAME}' input*.txt
```

If you do not want to start over with `port 0` for each input file you need to run awk just once (so it knows the current global value). Alternatively to `NR==1{p=1000}`, you can use the simpler logic from *Option 1*:

```
awk 'FNR==1{sub("input", "output", FILENAME)} $1=="local-ip"{$4=1000+p++} {print >> FILENAME}' input*.txt
```

Comment: Option 2 worked for me.

Comment: what I meant was that my requirement is getting fulfilled with this solution `awk 'FNR==1{sub("input", "output", FILENAME)} $1=="local-ip"{$4=1000+p++} {print >> FILENAME}' input*.txt` . **I get this output** `output1.txt output2.txt output3.txt output4.txt output5.txt output6.txt output7.txt output8txt output9.txt output10.txt`

Comment: @MuhammadIlyas Yep I know. But that is not solved by the currently accepted answer.